# is it possible to filter artifacts in Maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Is it possible to exclude some artifacts during release:prepare or release:perform? We don't need all the artifacts put on nexus, only two main ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you actually want to do is to **release** all modules (to handle proper versioning, dependencies, etc.) and only skip **deploying** some of them.

If so, you can skip particular module for `maven-deploy-plugin` by its configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or user property:

```
<properties>
    <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```